# Does the fighter's Action Surge work with ranger's Dread Ambush?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

On the tabletop when you have dread ambush (lv3 ranger) you get 1 extra attack when you use your action to attack on your first turn, this means when you use action surge (lv2 fighter) to get another action to attack with you get another extra attack. Does this work the same on Baldur's Gate 3? I'm planning on making a 3 lvs in assasin rogue, 3 lvs in gloomstalker ranger and 2 lvs in fighter build.

Answer (score 1):

To the best knowledge, all bonuses work independently, so you can't get a bonus triggering a bonus.

If you have a Dread Ambusher feat from the Gloom Stalker class:

> On the first turn of combat:
> Movement Speed increases by 3m.
> Gain an additional attack that deals +1d8 damage.

and the Action surge from the lvl 2 fighter

> Immediately gain an extra action to use this turn.

Assuming you have only one regular attack, you can:

- Get the bonus attack from Gloom Stalker, but only on the first round
- Attack
- Use action surge and attack again.

BUT, saying all that, your build is very sub-optimal, as you won't get the "Extra attack" feat, which is available for

> Barbarian at level 5
> Fighter at level 5 and level 11
> Monk at level 5
> Paladin at level 5
> Ranger at level 5
> College of Valour at level 6
> College of Swords at level 6

So you would do much better if you get either 5 levels of a ranger or 5 levels of a warrior. [There is a similar build for Astarion here](https://www.reddit.com/r/BG3Builds/comments/15rryyl/optimized_builds_for_companions/) with 5 Gloom stalker, 4 Rogue (thief is better than assassin) and 3 Battle master fighter.

With the build above you can get up to 5 attacks in the first round (more with certain weapons and feats)

Comment: The gloom stalker/thief/fighter build should be getting 8 attacks in the nova round, not 5.  2x Dread Stalker + Extra Attack, 2x normal action attack + Extra Attack, Action Surge, 2x normal + Extra Attack, and then two bonus action attacks with the off hand.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz umm, how do you get two dread attacks? Is that DND 5 version? Because I'm 99% sure that you just get one Dread Stalker as a bonus action, then you have your regular attack + extra attack from lvl feat. Power surge resets the regular + extra attacks. I admit I'm not sure about the offhands, since I rarely use them.

Comment: @Yasskier It's a semantics thing. In BG3 you "can make an additional attack on your first turn", but in DnD 5e you "make an additional attack when you take the attack action on your first turn", meaning you can make an additional attack each time you take the attack action.

Comment: @Yasskier an error on my part; Dread Striker doesn’t work with Extra Attack; still, 5 in the first round is low. 1 from dread striker, two from the attack action, with extra attack, two more from action surge providing the attack action with extra attack again, and two more bonus action attacks, for a total of 7 attacks in one round before factoring in options like Haste or Elixir of Bloodlust.